# Получить значение из переменных JS в в PHP и отправить в telegram

Tags: javascript, php

У меня есть несколько секции (квиз) с `input type=radio` (находятся не в form). И я получаю из них значение через прослушиватель событий после клика (две кнопки **назад** и **продолжить**.
В последней секции есть форма с тремя полями (Имя, номер и комментарий). При переходе на последнюю секцию
`<button class="btn btn-next">Продолжить</button>` меняется на `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-send">Отправить</button>`
Так же есть вот такой вот скрипт, который отправляет форму с последней секции (собирая значения из инпутов по  имени.
<?php

```
$firstStepValue = $_POST['firstStepValueph'];
// Вот так
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$comment = $_POST['user_comment'];
$token = "token";
$chat_id = "-715944511";
$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Комментарий пользователя ' => $comment,
  'Первое значение' => $firstStepValue,
  //и вот так (это пример)
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: success.html');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Как получить значения переменных из js в скрипт отправки телеграмм в PHP?

**Вот пример карточки с интпутами**

```
<div class="form-quiz-cards first-step-cards">
    <input class="type-design" type="radio" value="Корпоративная" name="type-design">
    <input class="type-design" type="radio" value="Частная" name="type-design">
    <div tabindex="1" class="form-quiz-card first-step-card">
      <h4 class="form-quiz-card__title">Корпоративная</h4>
      <img class="form-quiz-card__img first-step-img" src="img/first-step/corporate.png" alt="icon: Корпоративная">
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-quiz__card -->
    <div tabindex="2" class="form-quiz-card first-step-card">
      <h4 class="form-quiz-card__title">Частная</h4>
      <img class="form-quiz-card__img first-step-img" src="img/first-step/private.png" alt="icon: Частная">
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-quiz__card -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-quiz__cards -->
```

Comment: Ajax, fetch и так далее.

Comment: без аякса не смогу передать?